# Windows 2008 Local Admin and Domain Admin Password change in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

We are planning to make a network wide password change. we have 7 servers with Windows Server 2008 R2 and all in one Domain. Our plan is to first change the Local admin password of each server then once successful, we will proceed with the Domain admin password change.

is there anything that we need to check or consider before the making the changes to avoid any issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else create a second domain admin account, so you'll still be able to log into the domain even if the password change should fail for some reason. Then change the domain admin password. Once that succeeded, continue with the passwords of the local admins.

I'd suggest changing the password of the local administrator accounts via [Group Policy Preferences](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4683.how-to-change-a-local-administrator-password-with-group-policy.aspx) rather than changing it manually.

You can delete the additional domain admin account you created at the beginning after everything finished successfully.

Comment: thank you very much for the info. is it going to affect SQL and BES services or any running services?

Comment: If SQL Server is configured for AD authentication, you will be able to log in with the new password (no change required on that end). If you're running the SQL Server services under dedicated AD accounts and change their password, you have to enter the new password in the services' configuration, though. I have no experience with Blackberry servers.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. can you point me to the right direction on how to check if the Domain admin account is used in any Services. because it was also suggested to check the services associated to this account before making the changes. thanks again and your help is really appreciated. - Allen

Comment: Start `services.msc`. You'll see the account under which each service runs in the `Log On As` column.